# Recovering unsaved python file in fedora PyCharm after a sudden shutdown

Tags: fedora, pycharm, data-recovery

I was working with PyCharm IDE and my laptop suddenly shutdown because my battery died. When I rebooted my laptop I found that my two python files are empty. How I can recover their content?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a thing called `Local History`. So while you have opened desired file, select `Local History` (top menu -> VCS -> Local History) and it will show you all changes made in given file.

If you want to restore a deleted file, then select a parent directory of the deleted file. Again go to `Local History` and do the same.

Comment: tnx . you save my life :DDD

Comment: maybe you could mark that answer as a solution then :p

Comment: It also worked when I added an old version. For a second a I couldn't seen the version history but this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I made a research and I found this link , hope that's helpfull
http://www.opensourceforu.com/2012/05/how-to-recover-deleted-files-linux-1/